# select record from table 1 and copy to table 2 in C#

Tags: c#

i have a select statement  that select records from table1 and show in in datagridview,

how do i copy data that are shown in datagridview to table2 after the select statement.
below is my code of select item from table1

```
     public void getdata(){
        if (txt_Barcode.Text== "" )
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Please fill in something");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Detail.Rows.Count +1; i++)
        {

            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from asset where asset_no='" + txt_Barcode.Text + "'", conn);

        }
             da.Fill(Assetdt);         
        }



    #endregion

    public void fillds()
    {
        dgv_Detail.DataSource = Assetdt;
    }
```

to activate the event

```
 private void txt_Barcode_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {

            getdata();
            fillds();

            insertbar();

        }
    }
```

anyone noes how to do it?

Comment: This is a well-formed question, welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

First move your data from Data Grid view to datatable as :

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        DataColumn[] dcs = new DataColumn[]{}; 

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dgv.Columns) 
        { 
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(); 
            dc.ColumnName = c.Name; 
            dc.DataType = c.ValueType; 
            dt.Columns.Add(dc); 

        } 

        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgv.Rows) 
        { 
            DataRow drow = dt.NewRow(); 

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in r.Cells) 
            { 
                drow[cell.OwningColumn.Name] = cell.Value; 
            } 

            dt.Rows.Add(drow); 
        }
```

Then move data from datatable to sql table using foreach loop on datable.rows as :

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
Product product = new Product(); // make seperate class with same feilds as sql table
//Get the column values 
product.productId = dr["productId"];
 product.productName = dr[ProductName"];
 Product.Insert();//Insert will have inserting records into the dabtase
}
```

Product is seperate class as:

```
public class Product
{
   public int productId { get; set; }
   public string productName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks . the Product product is what? and where should i put these codes?

Comment: Product is seperate class which has same fields as of sql table columns.You can use then fields of this class in query as :   "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable2(ID, Name) values(Product.productId,product.productName)";

Comment: so my class will be  like this?

public class Product {
         Product()
         {

             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Detail.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
                 {
                     string sqlQuery = "FROM asset where asset_no='" + txt_Barcode.Text + "'";
                     string sqlInsertQuery = "SELECT INTO asset_data " + sqlQuery;
                     da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * " + sqlQuery, conn);
                     //Run ExecuteNonQuery using sqlInsertQuery     
                 }
             }
         }
         }

Comment: Product is seperate class..I have edited my solution..check it

Comment: with out product class.You can also write query for database insertion inside foreach loop as:  "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable2(ID, Name) values((int)dr["productId"],(string)dr[ProductName"])";

Comment: under foreach and others there are alot of red lines saying invalid token , identifier expected as dr["product"]

Comment: my table2  and table1 already has the same column already. do i still need this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18215/discussion-between-aizhong-and-wajid-ali)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this, is run a "SELECT INTO Table2" query after you display the data.

Practically, after putting up the data on the Datagridview, you need not be reading data from it rather you can re-use your query.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Detail.Rows.Count +1; i++)
{
string sqlQuery = "FROM asset where asset_no='" + txt_Barcode.Text + "'";
string sqlInsertQuery = "SELECT INTO Table2 " + sqlQuery;
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * " + sqlQuery, conn);
//Run ExecuteNonQuery using sqlInsertQuery    
}
```

To read more on SELECT INTO http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

To read more on Execute Non Query http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: string sqlQuery = "FROM asset where asset_no='" + txt_Barcode.Text + "'";
                    string sqlInsertQuery = "SELECT INTO asset_data " + sqlQuery;
                    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * " + sqlQuery, conn);
                    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand ("",conn );
                    cmd.CommandText=sqlInsertQuery ;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();   there is syntax error at select into   Thanks

Comment: aizhong, I do not see any problem with the query. Could you tell what's the nature of the error message/text?

Answer (score 1):

use SqlCommandBuilder for generating the insert command

```
        DataTable dtSource = null;
        //populate or assign dtSouurce here

        string connectionString = null;
        //assign your connection string here

        var tableName = "TABLE2";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(tableName, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
            var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

            connection.Open();

            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);

            builder.GetInsertCommand();

            foreach (DataRow row in dtSource.Rows)
            {
                dataSet.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                //dataSet.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(new object[]{ row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[2], "Some Else Values" });
            }

            adapter.Update(dataSet, tableName);

            connection.Close();
        }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx

Comment: Hi Ozgur. i am creating an desktop application.
it give me an error saying

The CommandType enumeration value, 512, is not supported by the .Net Framework SqlClient Data Provider. Parameter name: CommandType

Comment: are you using the System.Data (in System.Data.dll)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: are these usings added
"using System.Data;"
"using System.Data.SqlClient;"

Comment: i am using using System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Can you please check project properties and .net version. Is it .net 4 or .net 4 client. I do not have any other guess for the issue.